# Apache camel process(processor) method is not being called

Tags: java, apache-camel

I saw in another post how manually adding the camel context and starting it should work, but it hasn't for me. I double checked the from, and to paths and they seem to be correct. Not sure why it's not calling the method and would appreciate some advice

```
public class CsvRouteBuilder extends DdsRouteBuilder {
  private CsvConverterProcessor csvConverterProcessor;
  private CamelContext camelContext;
  @Autowired
  public CsvRouteBuilder(CsvConverterProcessor csvConverterProcessor) throws Exception {
    this.csvConverterProcessor = csvConverterProcessor;
    camelContext.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
      @Override
      public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("{{input.files.csv}}")
            .routeId("CSVConverter")
            .process(new Processor() {
              @Override
              public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                System.out.println("hitting");
              }
            })
            .to("{{output.files.csv}}");
      }
    });
    camelContext.start();

  }
```

Comment: Are your using `camel-spring-boot`? How are you starting your application?

Comment: Yes, using camel spring boot starter to start it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The processor is not called simply because your route is not properly declared such that Spring Boot is not aware of it.

The proper way is to make your class extend [RouteBuilder](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.camel/camel-core-model/latest/org/apache/camel/builder/RouteBuilder.html) to define your route(s) and annotate your class with [`@Component`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Component.html) to mark it as candidate for auto-detection when using annotation-based configuration and classpath scanning.

Your code should rather be something like this:

```
@Component
public class CsvRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("{{input.files.csv}}")
            .routeId("CSVConverter")
            .process(new Processor() {
                @Override
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                    System.out.println("hitting");
                }
            })
            .to("{{output.files.csv}}");
    }
}
```